# One small q on checking the file's name (Powershell)

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

```
$list = $web.Lists[$folder.ParentListId]
$itemCollection = $list.GetItems($query)
foreach ($item in $itemCollection){
Write-Host $item.Name
}
```

I wanna check if the file starts with "MDNSO", how can I write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the -like operator:

```
$something -like "MDNSO*"
```

For case sensitive comparison use:

```
$something -clike "MDNSO*"
```

Check the about_Comparison_Operators for more information:

```
Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators
```

Comment: one more question, how to check if a specific string($str1) contains a string($str2)

Comment: it worked! can you tell me how to remove the first . from a string please? Thank you!

Comment: Sure but I suggest you ask this in a new thread so others can benefit from it too.